# Amazon SageMaker Unsupported Media Type: image/jpeg

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I trained my own model using Tensorflow and Keras for image classification and I'm trying to deploy and use it with Amazon's SageMaker. I went through the process of converting the `mymodel.h5` file into a `mymodel.tar.gz` file and moving it to the SageMaker S3 bucket. Then, following a tutorial I created the SageMaker model using:

```py
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = 's3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/model/model.tar.gz',
                                  role = role,
                                  framework_version = '1.12',
                                  entry_point = 'train.py')
```

And created the endpoint to access the model:

```py
predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                                   instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

Now, since the point of creating this model was for image classification I'm trying to pass the image to my endpoint but have been getting a response of `Received client error (415) from primary with message "{"error": "Unsupported Media Type: image/jpeg"}"`. After reading up I feel like I may need to do some more work to have access to the `image/jpeg` content type as it seems like the defaults are `application/json`, `text/libsvm`, and `text/csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model has been converted into TF Serving Format, you can confirm the input your model expects using the `saved_model_cli`. Please see this [example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_serving_container/tensorflow_serving_container.ipynb) which depicts how to use the `saved_model_cli`. Kindly note how a prediction is made by converting an image to a [tensor](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_serving_container/sample_utils.py#L55).

Comment: The issue I'm having is the fact that the image is being passed to a Lambda function and I'm then passing that image to SageMaker via the invoke endpoint function. If I convert the image to a numpy array and use the predict model I have no issues (both locally and within a SageMaker notebook).

Comment: When we use the SageMaker Python SDK to make the invocation, the serialization and deserialization of the request and response is handled by the SDK itself. If you are using the boto3 `invoke_endpoint` API you will need to serialize the request yourself.  I usually take a look at how the SDK serializes the request and replicate the code in Lambda. Please see the SDKs [`NumpySerializer`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/serializers.py#L148) as an example. Kindly also remember to set the `ContentType` and `Accept` in the boto3 `invoke_endpoint` API call.

Comment: Currently, the image is being passed to my Lambda function as a base64 encoded string of the image. I do have Numpy imported to my Lambda function and was attempting to invoke the endpoint using the Numpy array created from the base64 string so I believe the issue is with my `ContentType`.  I'm assuming I'd be passing in the type of `application/json` so I'm a little confused how I should be formatting my request to my `invoke_endpoint` function then?

Comment: Alright it seems like I've started to understand a little better but I'm having some issues. I realized I need to write a custom handler for model so thats what I did. However, it seems like my model/endpoint is not using my handler for whatever reason. Inside of my `train.py` file I have a function `def input_handler(data, context)` that is meant to be my custom handler. For whatever reason it doesn't seem to be getting to that point though so any suggestions would be appreciated.